# Pass Variables In Inheritance (Obj - C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I working on a project in Obj-C where i have a base class (ViewController) and a Derived Class (MultiPlayer).
Now i have declared certain variables and properties in the base class.
My properties are getting accessed from the derived class but im not able to access the variables (int,char and bool type).
I'm completely new to Obj-C so i have no clue whats wrong.
I have used the data types which are used in C and C++.
Is there some specific way to declare variables in Obj-C??
If so, How?

Here are my files

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* backGroungImage;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView1;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView2;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView3;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView4;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView5;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView6;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView7;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView8;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blockView9;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *x;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *O;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* back1;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* back2;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



int chooseTheBackground = 0;
int movesToDecideXorO = 0;
int winningArrayX[3];
int winningArrayO[3];
int blocksTotal[9] = {8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2};
int checkIfContentInBlocks[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char determineContentInBlocks[9] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
bool player1Win = false;
bool player2Win = false;
bool playerWin = false;
bool computerWin = false;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(chooseTheBackground==0)
    {
        UIImage* backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBack1.png"];
        _backGroungImage.image=backImage;
    }
    if(chooseTheBackground==1)
    {
        UIImage* backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBack2.png"];
        _backGroungImage.image=backImage;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am not able to use the above declared variables in my derived classes!

Comment: Just a helpful hint, you can use an IBOutlet connection to have an array of IBOulets instead of having 9 individually named UIImageViews.  Ex. @property (nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *blockViews;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your variables are in the private `@implementation` of your class, if you want them publicly accessible, put them in your .h file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    int chooseTheBackground;
    int movesToDecideXorO;
    int winningArrayX[3];
    int winningArrayO[3];
    int blocksTotal[9];
    int checkIfContentInBlocks[9];
    char determineContentInBlocks[9];
    bool player1Win;
    bool player2Win;
    bool playerWin;
    bool computerWin;
}
```

Comment: When i do that, i get an error showing "Cannot declare variables inside @interface or @protocol"

Comment: Did you include the brackets?

Comment: Oh, you can't set your instance variables equal to anything in your .h file. My bad

Answer (score 0):

you can declare your ivars in the interface such as this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSObject* _myObj;
}
@property(attributes) NSObject* myObj
@end
```

or implementation:

```
@implementation MyViewController
{
    NSObject* _myObj;
}
@end
```

then declare your properties to use the variables (assuming you need/want properties for them)

you can to assign a variable to a property is like this:

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize myObj = _myObj; // this tells myObj property to use _myObj ivar
@end
```

the default synthesis is to use the property name prepended with an underscore if you don't specify your own.

However, you don't need to have access to the variables in your subclasses; just access the properties directly using `self.property`.

If you do need variable access such as if a property is `readonly`, then you must be aware that setting a variable outside the properties will no fire KVO notifications and you must do so manually if you need KVO.

Comment: This is very outdated. Ivars should no longer be declared in the `@interface`; if they're going to be declared explicitly, put them in the `@implementation` block. Prefer properties, though, in which case you don't have to declare them at all. The default name for a synthesized ivar is the property name, prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: agreed and edited. few reasons to use ivars over properties. usually I do it for a read only variable, but you can just use a class extension there.

Also I still declare in the interface for documentation purposes (being easily contained and exported). its really a matter of choice and there is usually no harm in declaring in the interface.

Comment: What do you mean, for a read only variable? The compiler won't let you access ivars outside the class by default, and there's no way at all to make them visible if they're in an extension. I would submit to you that you don't need to document your ivars -- they're not part of the class's interface with the outside world. They're inner details.

Comment: in the past my bosses have required documenting ivars.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you or saying you are wrong; only saying its something that is not always problem to do so. What I mean by a read only variable is having say an NSArray property that you want to have backed by an NSMutableArray because it is called frequently enough that doing an array copy is too expensive.